# Laravel Eloquent: Call to a member function connection() on null

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In Laravel I have a Controller like this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Dienstreise;

class DienstreiseController extends Controller
{
  public static function store()
    {
     $dienstreise = new Dienstreise;
     $dienstreise->user_id=1;
     $dienstreise->start_ort = "Hamburg";
     $dienstreise->ziel_ort = "Kassel";
     $dienstreise->save();
     return "OK";
  }
}
```

I have a route for that function, that works totally fine. (So the database-settings are 100% correct)

```
Route::get('/dienstreise', 'DienstreiseController@store');
```

But now I have a file in a folder in my public-folder, which needs to access that function in the controller too. (I know that sounds strange, but the file will get a POST Request from Dialogflow and so the file must be located in the public folder, otherwise they can't access it)

The file looks like this:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';

use App\Http\Controllers\DienstreiseController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Dienstreise;

$dr = DienstreiseController::store();
echo $dr;
?>
```

But I get a 500-HTTP-Error? The log:

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function connection() on null in /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:1140`

If I comment all the lines with $dienstreise... in the controller, I get the "OK", so the mistake must be there... But why does it work with the route? I'm confused. 
I read about uncommenting "$app->withEloquent();" in bootstrap/app.php, but there is nothing like this commented?

Comment: The application hasn't been bootstrapped.  Laravel's power is in the service providers, you haven't done anything to register/boot those providers, one of which being the database provider.   I don't see why you'd need to have a separate file in the public folder instead of just routing the POST request like any other request.

Comment: I have to specify a path to a webhook-file which contains e.g.:

`$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
if (isset($input["queryResult"]["action"])) {
    processMessage($input);
}`

and in that file I need the functions of the controllers - that's what i'm trying to achieve.
when someone could explain me how to do this with a route or how a route could act like a webhook I would love to do this?

Comment: Why can't you add that code to a controller method?

Comment: Devon is still correct - routes.php with Route::post( ... Controller@whatever ...)

Comment: uhm... i thought that doesn't work with the file_get_contents('php://input')?

Comment: you can put whatever php you want in the controller.  Even php://input stuff.

Comment: You can still do that, but you don't even need to.  Laravel's request object can handle JSON input out of box.   You may want to take a step back and read the Laravel documentation over.

Comment: I also had a situation with a hook that didn't get read into laravel properly.  I think it was a click bank hook.  In any case, that file_get_contents(php...) goes in the controller.

Comment: but do like Devon says and check for your json in the Request first.

Comment: thank you so much!!! it works. just one more thing... I have many models and need many of these 'store'-functions, that I access through the webhook-Controller. at first, I created to every model a controller. But now, I will just have the webhook-controller with maaany of these functions. isn't that confusing? but i heard that it's evil to access a function from another controller in a controller... so there's no other solution, am i right? (i hope you can understand that haha)